# Bullet Size in secure text field in iOS 14 display bit larger

Tags: ios, swift, security, textfield, ios14

In one of my application In the secure text field In iOS 14 bullet size is display bit larger then lower iOS version. I used the same font in all version.

[image: bullet display in iOS 13.5]

[image: bullet display in iOS 14]

Comment: You can simply increase bullet height by increase font size.

Comment: @RakeshPatel font size remains same in both version only bullet size display different. My problem is that bullet size in iOS 14 should display small.

Comment: The bullet size is fine in iOS 14, I just check.
Can you confirm that you created textfield in older Xcode version and opening in new Xcode? If you still face this issue then one workaround is to remove current textfiled and add again.

Comment: I used the custom font.

Comment: Is there any solution to this yet?